# How to discard line breaks in XSL-FO generated inside an eXist-db app?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, exist-db

I am a bit confused by several tips on white space handling in XSL-FO.

Sample (inside a paragraph):

```
<hi rendition="simple:italic"> jeden její prvek i(</hi>
<hi rendition="simple:bold-italic">E</hi>
<hi rendition="simple:italic">)</hi>
```

Attributes used on the paragraph (parent of all `hi`):

```
<xsl:attribute name="linefeed-treatment">ignore</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="white-space-treatment">preserve</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="white-space-collapse">true</xsl:attribute>
```

… produces

*jeden její prvek i(* ***E*** *)*

Formatting is good, all italics and bold italics are right. The problem are those spaces inside brackets.

I don’t know whether the problem could be caused by eXist-db treatment of separate elements. Whenever I open the file in eXide, it automatically breaks all inline elements on separate lines. If this was the case during serving the file to the FOP and if the linebreak was different than U+000A, I think I would be lost.

**UPDATE I**

The typical document processing inside my app is rather complex but the result is identical when I test it this way:

1. loading the doc with `doc()` function into a variable;
2. pass the variable through stylesheets and store it into another variable;
3. pass the second variable to `xslfo:render()` function;
4. stream the pdf result directly or save it into the DB.

It is possible to store the mid-product as `test.fo` but inside it it is not apparent why there is the problem with spaces. I guess the problem is typical for consequtive inline elements.

**UPDATE II**

If I try to generate pdf with this `fo`, the result is as expected:

```
<fo:root xml:lang="en" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="20mm"
      margin-bottom="10mm" master-name="PageMaster1">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="0mm" margin-left="0mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-bottom="10mm" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster1">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block text-align="justify">
        <fo:block>Lorem ipsum dolor 
          <fo:inline font-style="italic">test(</fo:inline>
          <fo:inline font-weight="bold">E</fo:inline>
          <fo:inline font-style="italic">)end</fo:inline>
          next lorem.</fo:block>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

If I try to store a testing `fo` file, the problematic part seems so:

```
<fo:inline font-style="italic" color="#91046e" language="cs">jeden její prvek i(</fo:inline> <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-style="italic" color="#5f3cb6" language="cs">E</fo:inline> <fo:inline font-style="italic" color="#91046e" language="cs">)</fo:inline>
```

Hence, it seems the problem could be really in my stylesheets.

For example, my template for italics:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:hi[@rendition='simple:italic']">
    <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="italic">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

I use no special whitespace or linefeed treatment at the moment. I tried it with no effect. I also tried to play with serialization, no effect. (I use it especially for producing smaller epub files but here the `fo` output remains the same. It guess serialization options are overwritten with Saxon, which simply takes the file as is, no matter how pretty printed.)

Comment: What version of eXist?

Comment: @joewiz , 3.1.1

Comment: What are your whitespace settings in conf.xml, and can you describe the pipeline your script follows to produce FO (or even better a reproducible test)?

Comment: In conf.xml I have defaults: `preserve-whitespace-mixed-content="no"` and `suppress-whitespace="none"`. When I set the second option to `both` or `trailing`, it changes new files’ formatting but does not help with FO―it seems it collapses all spaces outside the elements into one (which still remains in the result). As for the test, oh, I know, it is rather difficult because it needs XML/XSLT blocks and their whole handling.

Comment: Can you briefly describe the pipeline your script follows to produce FO? I'm asking so I have a sense of the variables involved.

Comment: @joewiz, update II. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing "white-space-treatment" to "ignore-if-after-linefeed" instead of "preserve"? (I was looking at the allowed values and their descriptions at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space-treatment.) If that doesn't do it, can you upload the full query used to generate the PDF you mention in Update II (the one that produces "expected results")? That could be the test case we use to build up try to reproduce/isolate the issue.

Comment: This works but only for cases of consecutive text and tags (like *text <hi>E</hi>.*). Then it becomes *textE*. I will test some other combinations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under 'Edit > Preferences', you could try adjusting the 'Soft wrap' and 'Show invisibles' preferences to see if you can work out whether eXide is or isn't adding white-space.

You could try setting the 'indent' and 'suppress-indent' parameters.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-serialization and  https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#xml-indent.

You could try writing out the FO that eXist would process, either to the log or to a file using the functions in the `http://exist-db.org/xquery/file` module (see http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/file&location=java:org.exist.xquery.modules.file.FileModule&details=true) to see (as best you can) whether or not eXist is adding white-space.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I should add the result is as expected whenever I “join” lines together manually in eXide (it only persists until the end of my session). When I turn on showing invisibles, there really are line breaks **but** I can’t match them with regex!